# table() function does not convert data frame correctly

Tags: r, data-mining

I am trying to convert a `data.frame` to `table` **without packages**. Basically I take [cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_between_data_frames_and_contingency_tables/) as reference for this and tried from data frame, both named or unnamed vectors. The data set is stackoverflow survey from kaggle.

`moreThan1000` is a `data.frame` stores countries those have more than 1000 stackoverflow user and sorted by number column as shown below:

```
moreThan1000 <- subset(users, users$Number >1000)
moreThan1000 <- moreThan1000[order(moreThan1000$Number),]
```

[image]

when I try to convert it to a `table` like

```
tbl <- table(moreThan1000) 
tbl <- table(moreThan1000$Country, moreThan1000$Number)
tbl <- table(moreThan1000$Country, moreThan1000$Number, dnn = c("Country","Number"))
```

after each attempt my conversion look like this:
[image]

Why `moreThan1000 data.frame` do not send just related countries but all countries to `table`? It seems to me conversion looks like a `matrix`.

Comment: Why do you want to convert to a table object? You data.frame already contains tabulated data.

Comment: because it doesn't work with `barplot` or `pie`

Comment: @MuratSEKERMCT ; i dont tihnk that squite right. Are you really just wanting this `barplot(dat$number, names.arg=dat$country)`

Comment: You might also want to look at `droplevels` if you want to exclude the countries from the original dataset that are not in `moreThan1000`.

Comment: Thanks for all I applied suggestions and now I can visualize most categories.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is because countries do not relate to each other. To each country corresponds a number, to another country will correspond an unrelated number. So the best way to reflect this is the original `data.frame`, not a table that will have just one `1` per row (unless two countries have the very same number of stackoverflow users). I haven't downloaded the dataset you're using, but look to what happens with a fake dataset, order by number just like your `moreThan1000`.

```
dat <- data.frame(A = letters[1:5], X = 21:25)
table(dat$A, dat$X)

    21 22 23 24 25
  a  1  0  0  0  0
  b  0  1  0  0  0
  c  0  0  1  0  0
  d  0  0  0  1  0
  e  0  0  0  0  1
```

Why would you expect anything different from your dataset?

Answer (score 0):

The function "table" is used to *tabulate* your data.

So it will *count how often every value occurs* (in the "number"column!). In your case, every number only occurs once, so **don't use this function here**. It's working correctly, but it's not what you need.

Your data is already a tabulation, no need to count frequencies again.

You can check if there is an object conversion function, I guess you are looking for a function `as.table` rather than `table`.